# Can't open SQLite database due out of memory error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having an issue opening my sqlite database for an iPhone app I'm writing. I thought I followed the tutorials verbatim but for some reason I am getting an "Out of memory" error.

```
-(NSString *) filepath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
}

-(sqlite3*)openDB{
    if(db == NULL){
        sqlite3 *newDBConnection;

        if(sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &newDBConnection) != SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_close(db);
            NSLog(@"%s SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));
            db = NULL;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"db opened");
        }

    }
    return db;
}
```

DB is an ivar and I am calling `db = [self openDB];` in the initialization method.

Comment: Log the error before closing the database. And confirm the `db.sqlite` file actually exists using `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Is this the first time you open SQLite in your app, or does it happen after you've been running a bit?

Comment: @Hot Licks- This is the first time I open SQLite in the app. I can't get it to open the first time.

Comment: @rmaddy - doesn't sqlite3_open make the file if it doesn't exist? That was I was told following the tutorials.

Comment: Can you open the file with `sqlite3` from the Mac command line?

Comment: And quote *the exact* error message you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sqlite3_open` is failing because you are using `NSDocumentationDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`.

The reason you're receiving the "Out of memory" error is that `sqlite3_open` is updating `newDBConnection`, but the `sqlite3_errmsg` is trying to use `db` (which is still `NULL`). And whenever you call `sqlite3_errmsg` with a `NULL` for the `sqlite3` pointer, SQLite somewhat confusingly returns an "Out of memory" message.

Also note that even if you fix the two above issues, note that you are calling `sqlite3_errmsg` after performing `sqlite3_close`. Make sure to get your error message before you call `sqlite3_close`.

E.g. I would suggest:

```
- (BOOL)openDB {
    if (db == NULL) {
        int rc;
        if ((rc = sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &db)) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"%s SQL error '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), rc);
            sqlite3_close(db);
            db = NULL;
            return false;        // open failed
        } else {
            NSLog(@"db opened");
            return true;         // open successful
        }
    }
    return true;                 // already open
}
```

Note, a minor point, given that `sqlite3_open` returns the error code, I would just save that directly, rather than calling `sqlite3_errcode` to get the code that was just returned.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't catch that

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I saw your code sample and its currently being used! Much appreciated